# How to put an image as background in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive, google-docs

How do I put an image as my background in Google Docs?

Comment: Welcome to the Web Applications - Stack Exchange site. Please take the [tour](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn the ropes.

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs doesn't support watermarks. 
However, there is a way to edit a file with a watermark (but not with the Google Docs API) with Microsoft Office (later you can edit it online)  

PART 1

- 1. Create a new  document (.docx) and open it with MS office

  2. Go to 'Page Layout' tab

  3. A couple of options should appear. Click 'Create custom watermark'

  Click on 'Picture Watermark' and select a photo

  Save the file with the watermark.

PART 2

- Once, you saved it, open up your browser and go to drive.google.com

  Right click on the screen (but not a file) and select 'upload file'

  Once, you upload the file, you will need a third-party app for google drive that can open .docx (As I said, google drive doesn't support watermarks). I suggest Only Office Personal.

HOW TO DOWNLOAD A THIRD-PARTY APP

  right click and mouse over to the 'new file' option. 
   Hit 'Connect more apps', then in the search bar type the name of the program and install it

Answer (score 0):

Putting images for backgrounds in Google Docs is easy enough to put in steps.

1. Make the Google Docs document (you don't have to do this if you are already on a document.)
2. Move your mouse over to insert and click on it. A list of things you can do will pop up, so move your mouse down to **Drawing** and click on it.
3. A toolbar will be on the Drawing page. So, go to the last thing on the toolbar, which is Image... and either choose an image or upload one.
4. Now that the image is on the screen, click on the T on the toolbar to add text boxes. Thus, you can write on your background. Write on it now, because when you submit it, you can't write on it.
5. You're almost done! Now just press "Save and Close" and it is ready to make big.